# Fill Factor--SQL Server, Is there a way to set Fill Factor across a database, server, or schema?

Tags: sql, sql-server, fillfactor

I understand that you can set a default fill factor but I want to change existing fill factors back to default across an entire server.

Comment: Script your objects for ALTER, find-replace the fill factor part, execute updated script - ?

Comment: Well  I found something that I think will work--just in case any future people are curious

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Database VARCHAR(255)   
DECLARE @Table VARCHAR(255)  
DECLARE @cmd NVARCHAR(500)  
DECLARE @fillfactor INT 

SET @fillfactor = 90 

DECLARE DatabaseCursor CURSOR FOR  
SELECT name FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases   
WHERE name NOT IN ('master','msdb','tempdb','model','distribution')   
ORDER BY 1  

OPEN DatabaseCursor  

FETCH NEXT FROM DatabaseCursor INTO @Database  
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  

   SET @cmd = 'DECLARE TableCursor CURSOR FOR SELECT ''['' + table_catalog + ''].['' + table_schema + ''].['' + 
  table_name + '']'' as tableName FROM [' + @Database + '].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
  WHERE table_type = ''BASE TABLE'''   

   -- create table cursor  
   EXEC (@cmd)  
   OPEN TableCursor   

   FETCH NEXT FROM TableCursor INTO @Table   
   WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
   BEGIN   

       IF (@@MICROSOFTVERSION / POWER(2, 24) >= 9)
       BEGIN
           -- SQL 2005 or higher command 
           SET @cmd = 'ALTER INDEX ALL ON ' + @Table + ' REBUILD WITH (FILLFACTOR = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(3),@fillfactor) + ')' 
           EXEC (@cmd) 
       END
       ELSE
       BEGIN
          -- SQL 2000 command 
          DBCC DBREINDEX(@Table,' ',@fillfactor)  
       END

       FETCH NEXT FROM TableCursor INTO @Table   
   END   

   CLOSE TableCursor   
   DEALLOCATE TableCursor  

   FETCH NEXT FROM DatabaseCursor INTO @Database  
END  
CLOSE DatabaseCursor   
DEALLOCATE DatabaseCursor
```

Comment: Its actually from this article https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1367/sql-server-script-to-rebuild-all-indexes-for-all-tables-and-all-databases/

Comment: but I dont really understand it yet--im new to SQL and figuring it out now

Answer (score 0):

BEGIN TRAN

DECLARE @table_name VARCHAR(MAX)

DECLARE table_cursor CURSOR LOCAL
FOR
SELECT
TABLE_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES

OPEN table_cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM table_cursor INTO 
@table_name

```
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0

        BEGIN 

        PRINT 'ALTER INDEX ALL ON '+@table_name+'
```

REBUILD WITH (FILLFACTOR = 100)'

```
        END
        CLOSE table_cursor;
    DEALLOCATE table_cursor;
```

ROLLBACK TRAN